# Сбор и обработка данных. Убрать задержки

Tags: python, база-данных

Пишу софт по обработке данных.
Сбор данных по RS485, собираю нормально. А вот что сделать дальше?

Сбором данных занимается небольшая программка и пока сохраняю данные в sqlite.

На основе принятых данных нужно принимать некоторые решения, причем нужно учитывать и прошлые данные тоже (поэтому пока данные и сохраняю в sqlite), этим будет заниматься другая программа. Но дело в том, что сначала писать данные в базу, а потом другой софтиной их читать можно, но появляются задержки, тем более что пока это все живет на Rabpberry Pi, а sqlite на ней работает не быстро.

Собственно вопрос в том, как организовать взаимодействие между частями утилит с минимальными задержками? Может быть это должно быть что-то типа Redis, или shared memory? Кто что посоветует?

Софт пока пишу на Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал работу через Redis.
Оказалось очень удобно, из монитора порта rs485 читаю данные и:

```
r.publish("ds18b20:{0}".format(addr), t)
r.rpush("ds18b20:{0}".format(addr), "{0}:{1}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s'), t))
```

И далее одной из программ читаю в реальном времени из r.psubscribe() и обрабатываю данные, а в другой программе по расписанию через r.lpop() читаю данные и сохраняю в sqlite для последующего неторопливого анализа